# Why is my instance variable acting like a class variable in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey, instantiation, instance-variables, base-class

Here is the basic structure of what I am trying to do:

```
OutputDebug % "~~~~~ START ~~~~~"

tempA := new ClassA()
tempB := new ClassB()
tempC := new ClassC()

tempA := 0
tempB := 0
tempC := 0

OutputDebug % "~~~~~ END ~~~~~"

return 

class Base {
    ivar := 0

    __New(inValue) {
        this.ivar := new Debug(inValue)
    }

    __Delete() {
        this.ivar := 0
    }
}


class Debug {
    value := 0

    __New(inValue) {
        this.value := inValue
        OutputDebug % "Create Debug [" this.value "]"
    }

    __Delete() {
        OutputDebug % "Delete Debug [" this.value "]"
    }
}


class ClassA extends Base {
    __New() {
        base.__New("A")
        OutputDebug % "Create ClassA"
    }

    __Delete() {
        base.__Delete()
        OutputDebug % "Delete ClassA"
    }
}


class ClassB extends Base {
    __New() {
        base.__New("B")
        OutputDebug % "Create ClassB"
    }

    __Delete() {
        base.__Delete()
        OutputDebug % "Delete ClassB"
    }
}


class ClassC extends Base {
    __New() {
        base.__New("C")
        OutputDebug % "Create ClassC"
    }

    __Delete() {
        base.__Delete()
        OutputDebug % "Delete ClassC"
    }
}
```

When this is run I get the following output in the debug log:

```
Create Debug [A]
Create ClassA
Create Debug [B]
Delete Debug [A]
Create ClassB
Create Debug [C]
Delete Debug [B]
Create ClassC
Delete Debug [C]
Delete ClassA
Delete ClassB
Delete ClassC
```

However, this is NOT what I would expect... this is the output I am looking for:

```
Create Debug [A]
Create ClassA
Create Debug [B]
Create ClassB
Create Debug [C]
Create ClassC
Delete Debug [A]
Delete ClassA
Delete Debug [B]
Delete ClassB
Delete Debug [C]
Delete ClassC
```

I am using Notepad++ and I have installed the DBGp plugin, it works and I can step through the script... the issues seems to be related to when the class 'Base' is instantiated as the base for Class[ABC]. When it hits the 'ivar := 0' line it is essentially deleting the previous object... which would make sense if it was a class variable, but NOT as an instance variable!

What am I fundamentally not understanding about how AHK is doing classes? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem was so very simple.

**DO NOT** name your classes after keywords! Variables are NOT case-sensitive in AutoHotkey, so 'Base' is the same as 'base'.

Therefore when I was using 'base' it was treating it as 'Base', which is why my observation of 'ivars' behaving like a class variable was true... because it was being used that way inadvertently!

If you rename the class 'Base' in the above sample code to 'BaseX' everything works as expected!

---

Over on the AHK Forums the creator of AHK also replied to my query there:

```
base only has special meaning if followed by a dot . or brackets [], so
code like obj := base, obj.Method() will not work. Scripts can disable the
special behaviour of base by assigning it a non-empty value; however, this
is not recommended. Since the variable base must be empty, performance may
be reduced if the script omits #NoEnv.
```

Source: [Objects](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm)

This is partly for backward-compatibility with scripts which used "base" as a variable name (before it became a "keyword"), and partly due to the way it is implemented. You may notice that ListVars shows base[0 of 0]: - it is implemented by the default base object, on the condition that the target is an empty variable named base. Consequently, it is possible to do this:

```
class Base  {
    M() {
        MsgBox % A_ThisFunc
    }
}
class C extends Base {
    M() {
        local base
        MsgBox % A_ThisFunc
        base.M()
    }
}
C.M()
```

You can hook base.Method() (where base is not an object) yourself by adding a __call meta-function to the default base object, but in script you can't get the name of the target variable.